# Share a folder with users on another computer without password

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, shared-folders

We have a "server" and 5 PCs in the office. There's a folder on the server which is shared and each of the PCs has full access to it (shared with Everyone). What I'm trying to do now is set it up so that only specific users have access to some of the files.

I know that in order to do this, all 5 PCs/users must have user accounts with the same usernames and passwords on the server. I've tried this with one of the users, but after creating the same user on the server and setting up the permissions, this user can see the share, but can't access it. I forgot to mention that currently, none of the users on the 5 PCs have passwords. Could this be a problem? I've read somewhere that things won't work if users are password-less. Is it possible to set this up without setting passwords on each user? All computers are running Windows 7 Ultimate x64. Thanks.

Comment: Unclear: Do you want to share without password the whole share or some files in the share? In any case, what's wrong with specifying a password, as this will happen only once and the credentials then saved for all future attempts? See also [public shared folders](https://superuser.com/questions/264825/windows-7-professional-with-workgroup-easiest-way-to-create-public-shared-folde).

Comment: Problem is that the share was visible, but we couldn't access the files (tried both ways, with and without passwords on the user accounts). However, it turned out my colleague messed up the permissions when moving the files from another computer (started applying them and stopped half-way). It's all working now, with passwords. Thank you.